# Find a textbox inside panel which is inside FormView

Tags: asp.net, textbox, formview, findcontrol

The formview has *more than 1 Panels*. My textbox is in the first panel. If I use this

```
TextBox myTxtBox = (TextBox)myformView.Row.FindControl("pnlID").FindControl("mytextbox"); <- does not work

Panel mypanel = (Panel)myformView.Row.FindControl("pnlID"); <- this works
TextBox myTxtBox = (TextBox) FindControlRecursive(mypanel,'mytextbox'); <-- this does not work
```

Can someone help? As as side question, I used a function [FindControlIterative](http://forums.asp.net/t/1107107.aspx/1/10) but I do not know which references to include for LinkedList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

**Markup**

```
<asp:FormView ID="formView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlID" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="mytextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

**Code behind**

```
TextBox myTxtBox = (TextBox)FindControlRecursive(formView1,"mytextbox");
```

Comment: First of all I get errors for `LinkedList ctls = new LinkedList();` inside the FindControlIterative because I do know what is the required namespaces.

Comment: The namespace is `System.Collections.Generic`. See: [LinkedList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)

Comment: Oops I do use master page as well. It asks for the variable T if I include Generic.

Comment: The solution provided by user "stelianx" in the forum post uses `LinkedList<Control>`. TBH there is not going to be a measurable different between the FindControlRecursive and FindControlIterative methods.

Comment: At what point in the page life cycle are you executing the code to retrieve the TextBox?

Comment: In my test project, I am putting the code in Click event of a button. I go into debug mode and it returns Null. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My answer: @jdavies solution is right. I was passing the wrong control to the function. I realized my formView1 was actually inside another panel, thus formview was not directly visible to code behind.